# Keeping a backup of asymmetric keys with the help of a certificate authority without losing the privacy

Tags: public-key, certificates, integrity

First I'll explain the problem, then I will also give a solution(it might be wrong) I've found for it, you let me know what you think about this solution and whether you have a better one.

Assume a user loses their asymmetric keys, now they are receiving a lot of messages without being able to decrypt them, so they need to fix this problem using a backup of their keys. Let's say they have also already given a copy of their keys to the CA, so they will refer to that and they have their keys again. However, if the CA has our private key, it can fabricate messages with evil purposes and add our digital signature to hold us responsible afterwards. What can we do to both have the privacy and the backup?

We can generate two pairs of keys instead of one. Then we'll give the CA both keys in the first pair(pub1,prv1), but only the public key in the second pair(pub2). Now the CA has to provide everyone two public keys of us, and determine which one is for verifying digital signatures(pub2), and which one should be used when they want to send us their messages(pub1). Now anytime we lose our keys, we can take back (pub1,prv1) from the CA to decrypt messages, and also we can use (prv1) to make digital signatures and the CA cannot play our role(I hope the English I've written here isn't too much wrong)
(Also as a side question: Do real-world CAs also provide backup?)

Comment: If I've understood correctly, you give CA the (pub1,prv1) unencrypted. that is a huge problem, right?

Comment: Typically, you don't give the private key to a CA.  You have to give it your public key (it needs to put it in the certificate it issues), but there's no reason why it needs the private key.  And, to answer your last question, CAs are not typically used to backup keys.

Comment: poncho thanks, so the keys don't typically get lost? kelalaka yes.